# Flex in Liferay Portal

Tags: apache-flex, portlet, liferay

I have deployed my Flex application as a portlet in Liferay Portal.

Everytime the Flex portlet gets loaded, I am seeing "Transferring data from sample.com...." in my browser's[Firefox 3.6] status bar. I am interested to know why I am getting this message displayed?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution to this problem as well.

The best I could find is that it's a Firefox bug.  I cannot verify this except by the following link.  The problem doesn't appear in Chrome or IE.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/151535

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Even I guessed that it must be a FF bug as I couldn't see this message in Safari or Chrome or IE.